# UIScrollView won't scroll after tapping button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have an app with a scrollview which contains several custom `UIButton`. I noticed that some of the `UIButton` (specifically, ones with an action set) cause the `UIScrollView` move to the top and prevents it from scrolling after it has been tapped. I also have an `NSTimer` running in the background. When I disable it I don't have this problem..

I heard that checking that the scrollview's  "delays content touches" setting and the "cancellable content touches" settings are on should fix it, but I still have the issue.

Any Ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you answered this yourself. The issue is obviously related to your NSTimer. Try running the NSTimer for `NSRunLoopCommonModes`. You do it like this:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: I am already doing this to prevent the scroll view from stopping the timer..but the problem persists